# Função mail e seus limites

Tags: php, envio-de-email

Estou desenvolvendo uma ferramenta para enviar e-mails em massa para uma lista de **20.000** e-mails, e o script é esse:

```
    <?php 
            $path = "listas/lista1.txt";
            $ponteiro = fopen ("$path", "r");
            $conteudo = fread ($ponteiro, filesize ($path));
            $linha = explode(" ", $conteudo);
            echo count($linha);
            echo " emails no arquivo.<br><br>";
            for ($f = 0; $f <= count($linha); $f++) {
                echo "Email:  ".$linha[$f]."<br>";
                $to  = $linha[$f];
                // subject
                $subject = 'Email 1!';
                // message
                $message = '<html><body>Teste</body></html>';
                // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
                $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
                $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
                // Additional headers
                $headers .= 'From: Teste <teste@teste.com>' . "\r\n";
                // Mail it
                if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
                {
                echo "MENSAGEM ENVIADA - ";
                }
                else
                {
                echo "NAO ENVIOU - ";
                }
            }
            fclose ($ponteiro);
     ?>
```

- Preciso saber qual o limite da função mail e dos servidores atuais ?
- Quantos e-mails por vez eu consigo enviar ?
- O que fazer  para não sobrecarregar o servidor ?
- Vantagens de instalar o SMTP no localhost e limites de SMTP local ?

Comment: Consulte sua hospedagem para saber quantos emails/horas podem ser enviados.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bem, respondendo por partes...

> Preciso saber qual o limite da função mail e dos servidores atuais?

A função mail não tem limites, *per se*, mas está limitada pelo memória máxima que pode ser alocada para o processo do PHP, pelo tempo do script *("script timeout")*, etc... Além disso, costuma ser má ideia não usar nenhum servidor de mail como intermediário. Os servidores de email controlam as listas de espera, retries, bounces, etc... que a sua aplicação não consegue.  Quanto ao servidor, não posso responder, porque depende do seu servidor...

> Quantos e-mails por vez eu consigo enviar ?

Na teoria quantos quiser, na prática ver a resposta acima. Precisa de ter em atenção que, a memória necessária para enviar cada email depende de factores como o tamanho do texto e os destinatários da mensagem.

> O que fazer para não sobrecarregar o servidor ?

Depende do intuito e do contexto do programa. Uma ideia é fazer uma lista de espera ("queue and defer"), isto é, o script principal chama um script secundário encarregue de enviar os emails e não aguarda pela resposta. Assim os emails são enviados em background. Outra ideia é usar um serviço próprio para o efeito. [O Mailchimp, por exemplo, tem uma API que permite criar e enviar campanhas](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/).

> Vantagens de instalar o SMTP no localhost e limites de SMTP local?

Bem, para enviar emails em "bulk", vai necessitar, quase de certeza, de um servidor SMTP, pelas razões apresentadas acima. No entanto, não aconselho a usar um SMTP local mas sim um remote dedicado como o Gmail ou o Mailchimp. Seguem as vantagens/desvantagens

Vantagens do servidor local:

- Controlo total sobre o servidor
- Sem limitações no número de emails, uptime, bandwidth, etc...

Desvantagens do servidor local:

- Muito provavelmente será marcado como SPAM
- Certos ISPs bloqueiam emails enviados a partir de IPs residenciais
- Tem que instalar, configurar e manter o servidor de mails

Dito isto tudo, no seu lugar, ou utilizaria a API do Mailchimp ou a API do Gmail para enviar os emails. Com o [zend-mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.mail.introduction.html), por exemplo, é trivial usar o Gmail. E há imensos tutoriais na net a explicar o processo.

Answer (score 2):

> Preciso saber qual o limite da função mail e dos servidores atuais ?

A função mail em si não tem limite, mas alguns provedores de hospedagem limitam o número de mensagens que você pode enviar no caso de hospedagem compartilhada, i.e. vários clientes no mesmo servidor.

> Quantos e-mails por vez eu consigo enviar ?

O principal limite é o tempo de execução. Normalmente existe um limite de 30 segundos, mas você pode eliminar o limite com a função set_time_limit(0) . No entanto, em alguns provedores de hospedagem não é permitido usar essa função.

> O que fazer para não sobrecarregar o servidor ?

Depende de como pretende enviar. Em geral o envio de email não causa sobrecarga em termos de uso de CPU porque apenas requer comunicação de processos ou de rede com servidores, e como isso são apenas operações de I/O (entrada e saída) não consomem CPU.

O que mais consome CPU é a composição das mensagens em si. O que se passa é que os padrões de email requerem que você codifique devidamente mensagens em formato MIME.

Isso significa que por exemplo caracteres de 8 bits (letras com acentos e cedilhas) devem ser codificados no corpo da mensagem usando codificação quoted-printable, coisa que você não está fazendo no exemplo acima.

A partir do PHP 5.3 existe integrada no PHP a função quoted_printable_encode. É muito mais rápida e simples do que tentar codificar o texto com rotinas em PHP como era necessário nas versões anteriores.

De resto não recomendo que reinvente a roda e tente fazer manualmente como fez no seu exemplo a composição de mensagens de email. Existem muitas classes prontas para fazer isso que sabem como compor mensagens de acordo com os padrões de email da Internet. Você não precisa aprender todos padrões para usar essas classes.

Eu uso a classe [MIME message](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/9-PHP-PHP-mailer-to-compose-and-send-MIME-messages.html) que inclusivamente é otimizada para o envio de email em massa. Tenho um site que envia em torno de 5 milhões de newsletters por mês. Algumas newsletters vão por email para mais de 400,000 assinantes.

Essa classe tem recursos de cache para reutilizar conexões mensagens compostas iguais enviadas para destinatários diferentes.

No site iMasters tem um artigo mais detalhado a explicar como funciona o [envio de email em massa em PHP usando otimizações inteligentes](http://imasters.com.br/linguagens/php/enviando-email-em-massa-rapidamente-em-php-usando-otimizacoes-inteligentes/) com esta classe.

> Vantagens de instalar o SMTP no localhost e limites de SMTP local ?

Nesta pergunta você presume que precisa de um servidor de SMTP para enviar mensagens. Isso não é verdade. É um equívoco comum. Vou tentar explicar sem entrar em muitos detalhes técnicos.

SMTP é um protocolo para receber mensagens. Quem recebe é o servidor de SMTP. Você só precisa de um servidor de SMTP se precisar de receber mensagens.

Em PHP para enviar email em sistema Linux, a função mail usa um programa local chamado sendmail que injeta a mensagem no servidor de email local.

A mensagem fica na fila do servidor de email e mais tarde o servidor de email envia a mensagem comunicando com o servidor de SMTP de destino do domínio do email do destinatário.

Portanto o PHP em si não usa SMTP em Linux. O PHP usa SMTP em Windows porque normalmente o Windows não vem com o servidor de email e por isso o PHP precisa comunicar com um servidor de SMTP do seu provedor que normalmente está noutra máquina.

Alguns sites usam serviços de email externos como da Amazon ou MailChimp porque o provedor de hospedagem não instala servidor de email local nem oferece servidor de SMTP para delegar a entrega de mensagens.

No entanto esses serviços ficam muito caros quando você excede os limites das contas gratuitas, o que parece ser o seu caso.

No seu caso, eu recomendo instalar um servidor de email local, tipo postfix ou qmail, para não ter pagar altas contas de email.

Note que quando digo servidor de email local, estou-me referindo a um servidor de email na sua máquina de hospedagem, não no seu computador pessoal que tem em casa ou na sua empresa.

Se não tiver um servidor de email instalado, talvez precise de um plano de servidor virtual (VPS) ou servidor dedicado para instalar caso o seu provedor de hospedagem não forneça um.

No entanto precisa de ter cuidado para configurar o registro TXT SPF do seu domínio para as mensagens não serem consideradas spam. Também precisa ter esse cuidado se recorrer a um servidor SMTP externo.

Se tiver dúvidas sobre isto, pode comentar abaixo, ou crie uma nova questão.